# DynamicDNS with A Records

Tags: dns, dynamic-dns, domain-name

I don't have a static IP and am running a small webserver from a VirtualBox VM. I can point the A record on the domains to my public IP, but when it changes everything will stop.

So I got a dynamic dns account, but don't know how to pull this off. A records, by my understanding, are what resoles a FQDN to an IP. So I can't enter my dynamicdns into the A record as it is a FQDN.

Is there anyway to have a domain name point to a DynamicDNS FQDN?

Also not sure if this is a SuperUser question or a server fault question. If it's in the wrong place I'm happy to repost elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use a CNAME.

There are different types of domain name system (DNS) resource records (RRs).

An A record contains a name (system.example.com) which points to an IPv4 address (192.0.2.50)

An AAAA record contains a name (system.example.com) and points to an IPv6 address (2001:db8:57::62:a89f)

A CNAME contains a name (system.example.net) and points to a name (system.example.com).

If I recall my RFC standards right, you're not supposed to point a CNAME to a domain name that uses a CNAME.  You're supposed to point a CNAME to a domain name that has an AAAA record and/or an A record.

Configuration is usually simple.  If you know where to specify an AAAA RR or an A RR, then you usually specify a CNAME in that same place.

Comment: I'm not sure if a cname leads to a redirect. In that case the OP should be aware that his TLD could show up as the dyndns name. If I'm not mistaken there are some providers offering dyndns for your own domains so it depends on the setup. Beware that there is a propagation time for DNS entries to be updated as they might be cached on multiple levels.